# IPython error: /usr/local/bin/iptest: Permission denied

Tags: python, macos, ipython, sudo, permission-denied

I'm trying to install iPython in Snow Leopard in Terminal.

In the terminal window I type:

```
$sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 ipython
```

I get the following result:

```
Searching for ipython
Best match: ipython 0.10.1
Processing ipython-0.10.1-py2.6.egg
ipython 0.10.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing iptest script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/iptest: Permission denied
```

Is there a reason why I keep getting the "error: /usr/local/bin/iptest: Permission denied"? I only have one account on my mac but I'm guessing that it may have something to do with admin or root access, but I thought using $sudo would allow it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but isn't there a binary package you could install?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to mess up with your system python and use virtualenv instead.

This would avoid permission problems too.